# requirejs initialize method run before everything else

Tags: requirejs, momentjs

I'm using require.js and moment.js and want to set the language globally before any module is loaded. However, I can't seem to find an appropriate way to run an init-method that is guaranteed to be run first.

i.e. in my main.js

```
requirejs(['mymodule'], function(mymodule) {
  moment.lang('fr'); // This gets run second, but I want it to get run first
  mymodule.printMonth();
});
```

mymodule.js:

```
define(function() {
  var string = moment().format('MMMM'); // This gets run first

  ...
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either [return a function](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#funcmodule) in your module that you call after moment.lang() or use a helper module that loads moment with the right configuration.

```
define(["moment"], function (moment) {
    moment.lang('fr');
    return moment;
});
```